# Imagen en spring

Tags: java, jsp, spring, imagen

me ha surgido un problema al intentar mostrar las imagenes en el jsp ya sea desde el propio workspace o desde el propio disco duro.

Mi configuración del xml es la siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jcg.spring.hibernate" />

    <!-- Resolves Views Selected For Rendering by @Controllers to *.jsp Resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/ Folder -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

<!--    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/img/" /> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/disco/**" location="file:C:/lacasadelasabuelas/imagenes/" />
</beans>
```

Y tengo en el jsp lo siguiente:

```
<img src="/imgInterno/Calefaccion.png" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" 
     alt="LaCasadelasAbuelas">
```

¿Me podéis ayudar? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué servidor de aplicaciones estas utilizando?

Comment: ¿Puedes dar más información sobre el error que estas teniendo?

Comment: Darth Vader, esto usando un servidor Tomcat, porque ya lo tenía configurado de una aplicación en JSF que hice anteriormente. Si me recomiendas otro y es mejor, no tengo problema en cambiar.

Comment: Me esta dando un error de 404 a pesar que tengo las imagenes en el directorio "resources".